# Android, login issue

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am currently developing an Android application. I am getting following error in the log cat when I try to login.

```
11-30 21:23:18.694: E/JSON Parser(1914): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
11-30 21:23:18.923: W/dalvikvm(1914): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3e56288)

11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=localhost/BCASStudentInfo/login.php
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at com.bcas.bcasstudentinfo.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:110)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at com.bcas.bcasstudentinfo.Login$TryLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:134)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at com.bcas.bcasstudentinfo.Login$TryLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-29 22:23:17.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1858):     ... 5 more
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858): Activity com.bcas.bcasstudentinfo.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@b45b4a40 that was originally added here
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.bcas.bcasstudentinfo.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@b45b4a40 that was originally added here
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at com.bcas.bcasstudentinfo.Login$TryLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:119)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at com.bcas.bcasstudentinfo.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:70)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-29 22:23:22.417: E/WindowManager(1858):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The codes I have used were included here.
**Login.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.bcas.bcasstudentinfo.R;
import com.example.bcasstudentinfo.student_home;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Login extends Activity {
    private Button login;
    private EditText user, pass;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();
    //private static final String LOGIN_URL="http://10.0.2.2/BCASStudentInfo/login.php";
    private static final String LOGIN_URL="localhost/BCASStudentInfo/login.php";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS="success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE="message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        assigncomponent();
        try{
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                /*Thread log= new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                    Intent openHome=new Intent("com.bcas.bcasstudentinfo.STFHOME");
                    startActivity(openHome);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
            };
            log.start();*/
                new TryLogin().execute();
                /*dialog= new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Attemting Login");
                dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.show();

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Nusername", user.getText().toString()));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Npassword", pass.getText().toString()));
                //String valid = "1";
                String response = null;
                try {
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://localhost/BCASStudentInfo/login.php", postParameters);
                    String res=response.toString();
                    Log.d("res:", res);

                   // res = res.trim();
                    res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");                              
                    //error.setText(res);

                   if(res.equals("1")){
                       Intent openHome=new Intent("com.bcas.bcasstudentinfo.STFHOME");
                    startActivity(openHome);}
                    else{
                         dialog.setMessage("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password"); }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

            }

            }

    );}catch(Exception e){
        dialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
    }

    class TryLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog= new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Attemting Login");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int success;
            String username=user.getText().toString();
            String password=pass.getText().toString();
            try{
                List<NameValuePair> params= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Nusername", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Npassword", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                JSONObject json=jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                success=json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if(success==1){
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    // save user data
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Login.this);
                    Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("username", username);
                    edit.commit();

                    Intent i=new Intent(Login.this,student_home.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }

            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
            if(file_url!=null){
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    private void assigncomponent(){
        login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_personal);
        user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_user);
        pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_pass);
    }  
    }
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");
 //$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
        //mysql_select_db("bcasdb",$con);

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //gets user's info based off of a username.
    $query = "
            SELECT
            `tbl_user_login`.`u_id`,
            `tbl_user_login`.`u_username`,
            `tbl_user_login`.`u_password`,
            `tbl_user_login`.`u_privilege`,
            `tbl_user_login`.`user_type`,
            `tbl_user_login`.`u_user_reg_id`
            FROM `bcasdb`.`tbl_user_login`;
            WHERE  `tbl_user_login`.`u_username` = :username
            ";

    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['Nusername']
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message.
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));

    }
    $validated_info = FALSE;

    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {
        if ($_POST['Npassword'] == $row['u_password']) {
            $login_ok = TRUE;
        }
    }
    if ($login_ok) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
} else {
echo "Empty Post";
}
header('Content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

**Confic.inc.php**

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "bcasdb";    
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

    try
    {

        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array)
        {
            foreach($array as &$value)
            {
                if(is_array($value))
                {
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value);
                }
                else
                {
                    $value = stripslashes($value);
                }
            }
        }

        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST);
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET);
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE);
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    session_start();
?>
```

**JSONParser class**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;

            // Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Close the input stream.
            is.close();
            // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return the JSON Object.
        return jObj;

    }


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

I can’t figure out the problem, can anyone help?

FOR YOUR INFORMATION: I am using WAMP Server and using the emulator in the eclipse for testing.

Comment: You're trying to show a Dialog after you've exited an Activity.  for this error "Activity com.bcas.bcasstudentinfo.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@b45b4a40 that was originally added here"  try to remove and check once agian..

Comment: so it sais "E/JSON Parser(1914): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject". This means that you are trying to convert to JSON a bad String...bad formatted. Try to debug that string first, show it in a Log.v("the string",my_string); and check if it's  a json object with all the { } required

Comment: Sorry i am new the android, actually where did i want to put the "LOG". The value will contain in the "json" variable and so it will take as an json object

Answer (score 1):

Your login URL should be

```
http://localhost/BCASStudentInfo/login.php
```

rather than

```
localhost/BCASStudentInfo/login.php
```

Comment: i have tried using 

`private static final String LOGIN_URL="http://10.0.2.2/BCASStudentInfo/login.php";`

Comment: i am still getting the same error, my application stoped working